# Keras fit and fit_generator returns quite different results

Tags: debugging, keras

Keras fit and fit_generator returns quite different results, fit_generator drops precision almost 20%. I do use shuffle in the data generator. I have attached my data_generator below. Thank you !

```
def data_generator(input_x, input_y, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE):
    loopcount = len(input_x) // batch_size
    while True:
        i = random.randint(0, loopcount - 1)
        x_batch = input_x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        y_batch = input_y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        yield x_batch, y_batch
```

and my model.fit_generator is showing below:

```
    model.fit_generator(generator = data_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE),steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) // BATCH_SIZE, epochs = 20, validation_data = data_generator(x_val, y_val, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE), validation_steps = len(x_val) // BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: There is very little information here, but your steps per epoch and validation steps are wrong, as you are not dividing by the batch size so the model is being evaluated on a different dataset.

Comment: Hi Matias, I do devide batch size on steps per epoch and validation steps. (steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) // BATCH_SIZE, validation_steps = len(x_val) // BATCH_SIZE))

Comment: Ah yes true, then provide the fit call and more information as well.

Comment: model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
          epochs=20, batch_size=10)

Comment: fit is as above, the only difference is fit_generator uses data generator which is provided before.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR; use `fit` instead of `fit_generator`**

Starting in TensorFlow 2.x, the `fit` method can take generators as inputs, so instead of using `fit_generator`, I would highly recommend simply using `fit`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not the solution but a similar problem. I think both of these problems are related and resolving one can be the solution to other.

[fit_generator is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600127/keras-fit-generator-and-fit-results-are-different)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your generator picks batches randomly, which will likely end up with duplicate or unused batches within the same epoch.

To avoid this, you could something like this (untested):

```
    def data_generator(input_x, input_y, batch_size):
        loopcount = len(input_x) // batch_size
        batches = range(loopcount)
        random.shuffle(batches)
        i = 0
        while True:
            b = batches[i]
            x_batch = input_x[b*batch_size:(b+1)*batch_size]
            y_batch = input_y[b*batch_size:(b+1)*batch_size]
            i += 1
            yield x_batch, y_batch
```

However, you will lose some patches if your data amount is not a multiple of batch_size. You could code around that though and return a final batch that is smaller than batch_size.

Or, you could use an Iterator:

```
class MyIterator(Iterator):
    def __init__(self, x, y, batch_size, shuffle=True, seed=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        super(MyIterator, self).__init__(x.shape[0], batch_size, shuffle, seed)

    def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
        return self.x[index_array], self.y[index_array]
```

Then start the training like this:

```
    train_iterator = MyIterator(x_train, y_train, batch_size)
    val_iterator = MyIterator(x_val, y_val, batch_size)
    model.fit_generator(generator=iterator, 
                        steps_per_epoch=len(train_iterator),  
                        validation_data=val_iterator, 
                        validation_steps=len(val_iterator),
                        epochs=20)
```

The iterator will handle the remaining patches for you, effectively creating a last batch that may be smaller than batch_size.

Edit: Following the discussion over at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2389, it is very important to shuffle the data when you write your own custom generators.