# Accuracy killed when using ImageDataGenerator TensorFlow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have already made a post here but the answers have not been quite helpful, probably because I did not phrase the question right. Now I know more about the problem but still cannot find the solution.

I tried to build a Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow Keras to predict on the CIFAR100 dataset. I managed to achive decent results with 60% validation accuracy and wanted to add image augmentation.

I noticed a significant drop in accuracy so I decided not to augment any data but to try and see if the results would remain the same if I used the ImageDataGenerator to feed data to the model but **without any augmentation**.

The accuracy drop remained, I tried to check the way the ImageDataGenerator delivers data but everything seems in order, the labels for images also appear to be correct. I also noticed that the loss was still decreasing somewhat similarly as when I was not using an ImageDataGenerator.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    
)

datagen.fit(train_images)

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128), shuffle=False, epochs=250, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])

# Without ImageDataGenerator
# history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=128, epochs=250, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

I do not think the architecture is important since the problem is with the ImageDataGenerator but if any kind soul wants to check the code and the output here is the google collab notebook link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y7UZHp8cXi2dOyMeHW22SkOuWolNhRZQ?usp=sharing

I really do not know what to do anymore.

EDIT:
The accuracy drops from ~0.6 to 0.01 w

I have been informed to provide everything in the question so here are the results:

**Results when using empty ImageDataGenerator (Interrupted because of little progress)**

So just to clarify, **no data augmentation has been done, ImageDataGenerator is empty.**

I tried setting the parameter ***shuffle*** of ***datagen.flow*** to ***False***, but it had little to no impact on the results.

```
>Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz
>
>169009152/169001437 [==============================] - 2s 0us/step
>
>Epoch 1/250
>
>  2/390 [..............................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 5.3008 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0238s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0366s). Check your callbacks.
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 29s 74ms/step - loss: 4.5465 - accuracy: 0.0041 - val_loss: 4.6752 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
>
>Epoch 2/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 4.1575 - accuracy: 0.0067 - val_loss: 4.5212 - val_accuracy: 0.0019
>
>Epoch 3/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 3.9204 - accuracy: 0.0115 - val_loss: 4.3019 - val_accuracy: 0.0034
>
>Epoch 4/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 3.6618 - accuracy: 0.0180 - val_loss: 3.8335 - val_accuracy: 0.0383
>
>Epoch 5/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 3.3415 - accuracy: 0.0174 - val_loss: 3.3168 - val_accuracy: 0.0369
>
>Epoch 6/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 3.0612 - accuracy: 0.0132 - val_loss: 3.3109 - val_accuracy: 0.0076
>
>Epoch 7/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 2.8365 - accuracy: 0.0121 - val_loss: 3.0244 - val_accuracy: 0.0249
>
>Epoch 8/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 2.6400 - accuracy: 0.0120 - val_loss: 2.7754 - val_accuracy: 0.0232
>
>Epoch 9/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 2.4838 - accuracy: 0.0110 - val_loss: 2.7786 - val_accuracy: 0.0085
>
>Epoch 10/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 2.3305 - accuracy: 0.0102 - val_loss: 2.2827 - val_accuracy: 0.0191
>
>Epoch 11/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 2.1901 - accuracy: 0.0107 - val_loss: 2.2275 - val_accuracy: 0.0089
>
>Epoch 12/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 28s 71ms/step - loss: 2.0822 - accuracy: 0.0104 - val_loss: 2.1312 - val_accuracy: 0.0197
>
>Epoch 13/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.9752 - accuracy: 0.0106 - val_loss: 2.2580 - val_accuracy: 0.0253
>
>Epoch 14/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.8751 - accuracy: 0.0105 - val_loss: 1.9996 - val_accuracy: 0.0122
>
>Epoch 15/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.7874 - accuracy: 0.0103 - val_loss: 2.0046 - val_accuracy: 0.0085
>
>Epoch 16/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.7062 - accuracy: 0.0099 - val_loss: 1.9315 - val_accuracy: 0.0140
>
>Epoch 17/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.6240 - accuracy: 0.0102 - val_loss: 1.8867 - val_accuracy: 0.0079
>
>Epoch 18/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.5656 - accuracy: 0.0099 - val_loss: 1.8539 - val_accuracy: 0.0117
>
>Epoch 19/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.4992 - accuracy: 0.0101 - val_loss: 1.8715 - val_accuracy: 0.0124
>
>Epoch 20/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.4285 - accuracy: 0.0102 - val_loss: 1.7864 - val_accuracy: 0.0092
>
>Epoch 21/250
>
>390/390 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 1.3764 - accuracy: 0.0100 - val_loss: 1.8202 - val_accuracy: 0.0119
>
>Epoch 22/250
>
>159/390 [===========>..................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 1.2974 - accuracy: 0.0106
>
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>KeyboardInterrupt
```

Results without ImageDataGenerator

```
>Epoch 1/250
>
>  2/391 [..............................] - ETA: 17s - loss: 5.4772 - accuracy: 0.0078WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0320s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0579s). Check your callbacks.
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 67ms/step - loss: 4.5878 - accuracy: 0.0207 - val_loss: 4.7042 - val_accuracy: 0.0134
>
>Epoch 2/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 67ms/step - loss: 4.2055 - accuracy: 0.0522 - val_loss: 4.2270 - val_accuracy: 0.0538
>
>Epoch 3/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 3.8648 - accuracy: 0.0883 - val_loss: 4.1179 - val_accuracy: 0.0814
>
>Epoch 4/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 3.5519 - accuracy: 0.1421 - val_loss: 3.8452 - val_accuracy: 0.1325
>Epoch 5/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 3.2509 - accuracy: 0.1952 - val_loss: 3.3625 - val_accuracy: 0.1882
>
>Epoch 6/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.9928 - accuracy: 0.2408 - val_loss: 3.2708 - val_accuracy: 0.2161
>
>Epoch 7/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.7977 - accuracy: 0.2809 - val_loss: 2.7619 - val_accuracy: 0.3035
>
>Epoch 8/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.6131 - accuracy: 0.3187 - val_loss: 2.5414 - val_accuracy: 0.3501
>
>Epoch 9/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.4598 - accuracy: 0.3517 - val_loss: 2.7046 - val_accuracy: 0.3255
>
>Epoch 10/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.3132 - accuracy: 0.3882 - val_loss: 2.2640 - val_accuracy: 0.4070
>
>Epoch 11/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.1848 - accuracy: 0.4189 - val_loss: 2.1943 - val_accuracy: 0.4327
>
>Epoch 12/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 2.0751 - accuracy: 0.4445 - val_loss: 2.2010 - val_accuracy: 0.4361
>
>Epoch 13/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.9770 - accuracy: 0.4687 - val_loss: 2.1503 - val_accuracy: 0.4551
>
>Epoch 14/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.8800 - accuracy: 0.4931 - val_loss: 2.1343 - val_accuracy: 0.4603
>
>Epoch 15/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.7966 - accuracy: 0.5125 - val_loss: 2.0326 - val_accuracy: 0.4885
>
>Epoch 16/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.7115 - accuracy: 0.5345 - val_loss: 2.0095 - val_accuracy: 0.4921
>
>Epoch 17/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.6370 - accuracy: 0.5557 - val_loss: 1.9143 - val_accuracy: 0.5168
>
>Epoch 18/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.5570 - accuracy: 0.5735 - val_loss: 1.8116 - val_accuracy: 0.5317
>
>Epoch 19/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.5038 - accuracy: 0.5871 - val_loss: 1.7452 - val_accuracy: 0.5520
>
>Epoch 20/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.4433 - accuracy: 0.6041 - val_loss: 1.8036 - val_accuracy: 0.5433
>
>Epoch 21/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.3753 - accuracy: 0.6204 - val_loss: 1.8993 - val_accuracy: 0.5321
>
>Epoch 22/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.3242 - accuracy: 0.6343 - val_loss: 1.9099 - val_accuracy: 0.5382
>
>Epoch 23/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.2704 - accuracy: 0.6474 - val_loss: 1.7647 - val_accuracy: 0.5667
>
>Epoch 24/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.2367 - accuracy: 0.6576 - val_loss: 1.7773 - val_accuracy: 0.5657
>
>Epoch 25/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.1795 - accuracy: 0.6715 - val_loss: 1.7160 - val_accuracy: 0.5766
>
>Epoch 26/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.1373 - accuracy: 0.6827 - val_loss: 1.7304 - val_accuracy: 0.5774
>
>Epoch 27/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.1082 - accuracy: 0.6923 - val_loss: 1.9430 - val_accuracy: 0.5465
>
>Epoch 28/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.0601 - accuracy: 0.7011 - val_loss: 1.8539 - val_accuracy: 0.5669
>
>Epoch 29/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 1.0185 - accuracy: 0.7152 - val_loss: 1.7887 - val_accuracy: 0.5778
>
>Epoch 30/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.9888 - accuracy: 0.7230 - val_loss: 1.7522 - val_accuracy: 0.5884
>
>Epoch 31/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.9584 - accuracy: 0.7310 - val_loss: 1.7597 - val_accuracy: 0.5903
>
>Epoch 32/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.9328 - accuracy: 0.7392 - val_loss: 1.7132 - val_accuracy: 0.5991
>
>Epoch 33/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.8958 - accuracy: 0.7499 - val_loss: 1.7338 - val_accuracy: 0.6036
>
>Epoch 34/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.8724 - accuracy: 0.7571 - val_loss: 1.7104 - val_accuracy: 0.6079
>
>Epoch 35/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.8450 - accuracy: 0.7624 - val_loss: 1.7668 - val_accuracy: 0.6038
>
>Epoch 36/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.8050 - accuracy: 0.7744 - val_loss: 1.9853 - val_accuracy: 0.5697
>
>Epoch 37/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.8056 - accuracy: 0.7736 - val_loss: 1.8849 - val_accuracy: 0.5859
>
>Epoch 38/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.7700 - accuracy: 0.7839 - val_loss: 1.8189 - val_accuracy: 0.6049
>
>Epoch 39/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.7545 - accuracy: 0.7874 - val_loss: 1.8237 - val_accuracy: 0.5989
>
>Epoch 40/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.7337 - accuracy: 0.7918 - val_loss: 1.8901 - val_accuracy: 0.5918
>
>Epoch 41/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.7108 - accuracy: 0.8002 - val_loss: 1.8254 - val_accuracy: 0.6090
>
>Epoch 42/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.6897 - accuracy: 0.8039 - val_loss: 1.8526 - val_accuracy: 0.6094
>
>Epoch 43/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.6723 - accuracy: 0.8099 - val_loss: 1.9535 - val_accuracy: 0.5924
>
>Epoch 44/250
>
>391/391 [==============================] - 26s 66ms/step - loss: 0.6665 - accuracy: 0.8138 - val_loss: 1.8447 - val_accuracy: 0.6037
>313/313 - 3s - loss: 1.8447 - accuracy: 0.6037
>0.6036999821662903
```

EDIT 2:
I understand that my architecture is flawed, and any help is appreciated, but I would kindly ask if you could help with the ImageDataGenerator problem for which I consider to have provided all relevant information.

Comment: What significant drop in accuracy are you talking about? There is no information abou tthat in your question. Also collab links are not useful, all the information should be in the text of your question.

Comment: And I will give you a spoiler, the architecture does matter, because there is a big issue in your network that prevents it from working properly.

Comment: I have provided the results in the post now.

Comment: Also the architecture, as I said there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Of course the architecture does matter when taking about the overall performance of the network, but in this case the only difference is the usage of ImageDataGenerator. Without the generator, the network is performing as expected so I figured the generator is the problem, sorry if there was any confusion.

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean? Does the architecture mistake directly correlate to the ImageDataGenerator problem?

Comment: In collab you are using ReLU as the activation of the output layer which is completely incorrect, it should be softmax. There is a good reason why I ask for the architecture and it has to be in the question. I also see other problems, but I will only reply to the information in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for helping, unfortunately it appears that my issue in question still remains.

Comment: That is just one of the issues, as I said, put all the information in the question.

Comment: Did your previous solution without ImageDataGenerator include any data augmentation?

Comment: @msg45f I only divided the training and test images by 255.0 but that is present in both implementations.

Comment: Had the same issue. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534387

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you've configured shuffle to be off on the generator. Everything else is fine.  There is no change in images or labels.  Note that by default, model.fit will shuffle input data, but when you use a generator you must configure the generator to shuffle. As such, when you did not provide a generator the input data was being shuffled and when you used the generator it was not being shuffled. This problem seems similar to what was encountered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600127/keras-fit-generator-and-fit-results-are-different?rq=1) question that addressed differences between fit and the now deprecated fit_generator methods.

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dWjhfGYz2H6niKmic_Hf7O-CO1ku7dZq?usp=sharing) is a copy of the notebook that I used to tinker around with.

When configured to shuffle the generator, I get reasonable convergence that is not dissimilar from providing the images directly.

#### With Generator

```
Epoch 1/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 69ms/step - loss: 4.6436 - accuracy: 0.0140 - val_loss: 4.6110 - val_accuracy: 0.0084
Epoch 2/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 67ms/step - loss: 4.4306 - accuracy: 0.0373 - val_loss: 4.5542 - val_accuracy: 0.0237
Epoch 3/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 67ms/step - loss: 4.2667 - accuracy: 0.0587 - val_loss: 4.2758 - val_accuracy: 0.0590
Epoch 4/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 67ms/step - loss: 4.1242 - accuracy: 0.0798 - val_loss: 4.1708 - val_accuracy: 0.0725
Epoch 5/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 4.0096 - accuracy: 0.0980 - val_loss: 3.9277 - val_accuracy: 0.1188
Epoch 6/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 3.8621 - accuracy: 0.1288 - val_loss: 4.5334 - val_accuracy: 0.0659
Epoch 7/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 3.7434 - accuracy: 0.1460 - val_loss: 4.5092 - val_accuracy: 0.0835
Epoch 8/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 68ms/step - loss: 3.5886 - accuracy: 0.1769 - val_loss: 3.8606 - val_accuracy: 0.1486
Epoch 9/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 69ms/step - loss: 3.4937 - accuracy: 0.1975 - val_loss: 3.9907 - val_accuracy: 0.1236
Epoch 10/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 70ms/step - loss: 3.3655 - accuracy: 0.2190 - val_loss: 3.4287 - val_accuracy: 0.2202
```

#### Without Generator

```
Epoch 1/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 69ms/step - loss: 4.6348 - accuracy: 0.0154 - val_loss: 4.5947 - val_accuracy: 0.0152
Epoch 2/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 68ms/step - loss: 4.4097 - accuracy: 0.0398 - val_loss: 4.4070 - val_accuracy: 0.0419
Epoch 3/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 4.2278 - accuracy: 0.0643 - val_loss: 4.4637 - val_accuracy: 0.0481
Epoch 4/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 4.0906 - accuracy: 0.0842 - val_loss: 4.3163 - val_accuracy: 0.0625
Epoch 5/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 68ms/step - loss: 3.9589 - accuracy: 0.1033 - val_loss: 4.3802 - val_accuracy: 0.0693
Epoch 6/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 68ms/step - loss: 3.8119 - accuracy: 0.1318 - val_loss: 3.8241 - val_accuracy: 0.1345
Epoch 7/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 3.7324 - accuracy: 0.1447 - val_loss: 3.6602 - val_accuracy: 0.1598
Epoch 8/10
391/391 [==============================] - 27s 68ms/step - loss: 3.6160 - accuracy: 0.1669 - val_loss: 3.6975 - val_accuracy: 0.1573
Epoch 9/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 3.4929 - accuracy: 0.1893 - val_loss: 3.5784 - val_accuracy: 0.1956
Epoch 10/10
391/391 [==============================] - 26s 68ms/step - loss: 3.4052 - accuracy: 0.2061 - val_loss: 3.3669 - val_accuracy: 0.2298
```

#### Comparisons

[image: Accuracy Plot]
[image: Loss Plot]

Comment: Wow, thank you for this comprehensive answer. Unfortunately, the only reason I have turned shuffle off is because with shuffle set to True it was not working either so I tried turning it off to see if there would be any difference.

Comment: So I took another look at your original code and just as you said, turning shuffle back on didn't do the trick. There was one other thing that I did that I hadn't thought was impacting it at first, but it seems to work as a minimal edit to your own code.  That was reshaping the label array so that it would be a 1D rather than 2D `tf.reshape(train_labels, (-1))`. Could you give this a try and see if it result is repeatable?

Comment: I was wondering what that line was for. No, it looks like is still does not work. Nevertheless, you are a god. No one has ever been this dedicated to helping me before. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, I have made a mistake, and this fix of yours does work. I cannot thank you enough, you are amazing. But how did you think to do this and why? Why is this necessary when working with a generator?

Comment: It appears that the network is learning slower and converges at a lower accuracy now, but it is certainly better than before

Comment: I am sorry for leaving so many comments, but the drop in accuracy was due to me setting an activation function to softmax in the output layer where there should be no activation function.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the change should have been necessary at all. The behavior overall was a bit confusing. Even before the fix, the loss was falling but the accuracy wasn't improving.  I thought there might be a problem with the 2D array as that is normally how I would pass one-hotted labels for CategoricalCrossentropy, not SparseCategoricalCrossentropy, though honestly if this was the issue the model should have raised an error due to the label array length not matching the number of outputs at the final layer.

Comment: I just had the same problem and applying `tf.reshape(train_labels, (-1))` fixed it for me. I think this is because when `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used, it assumes that the targets are 1D. If the targets are something like `[[1], [1], [0], [1], ...]`, then maybe during the evaluation the objects / values inside `y_pred` and `y_actual` are not compared correctly.